# Swift UIPicker getting selected value switches to default value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

I want to set a button text to UIPicker selected title.

I have the following code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var dureeBtn: UIButton!
@IBAction func changerDuree(sender: AnyObject) {
    picker.hidden = !picker.hidden
}
let _names = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
let _vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return _names.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return _names[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    dureeBtn.titleLabel!.text = _names[row]

}
```

And it works sometimes (approx. 50%), but on the other times it switches to default values.
Here are the screenshots: 
[image: not working]

[image: working]

Have anyone had this problem before?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear... What are you trying to do? What's happening instead? And what should we be looking at in the images you posted?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I want to set the text of my button (dureeBtn) to the UIPicker's selected index (as on the second screenshot). But sometimes, as on the first screenshot, it just changes to the default value

Comment: Have you noticed any particular circumstances where it's changed to that default value? What were you doing at the time?

Comment: no, just spin the wheel to another value.